# Different result of np.prod made by float ant int

Tags: python, integer

In accident, I found that `np.prod(alist)` make different results according to type of list element. For example,

`np.prod([8, 6, 9, 4, 7, 8, 8, 5, 1, 8, 4, 3, 8])`

`np.prod([[8.0, 6.0, 9.0, 4.0, 7.0, 8.0, 8.0, 5.0, 1.0, 8.0, 4.0, 3.0, 8.0]])`

To me, this makes no sense. What makes this difference?

Comment: Both of them return the same value to me, what difference are you talking about

Comment: I see your problem. What's happening is that you're encountering an overflow error, however numpy does not report it back as an error/warning. Therefore, the output may differ depending on the precision being used in the calculation.